# How can I disable a watchdog, once it has been enabled?

Tags: linux, watchdog

I created a watchdog daemon application with a time interval of 30 seconds; for every 5 seconds, I am trying to hit the watchdog counter, and it's working fine. If I kill this daemon process it shows the following:

```
mxc_wdt: Unexpected close, not stopping!
```

Then, my device gets reset after my time interval goes to zero (i.e.,hardware counter count down to zero).

I even configured `CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT=N` in kernel.

Is there any process to disable this watchdog functionality at user bash prompt?  I observed `disable not supported by this chip` in kernel `mxc_wdt_disable` function.

Answer (score 8):

Normally to shut down the watchdog driver you have to write a 'V' character to /dev/watchdog which you could do from a root bash prompt just with:

```
echo 'V' > /dev/watchdog
```

However, before you try to create your own watchdog driver take a look at the existing Linux watchdog daemon to see if it can do the job. A good start is my page here: http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/~psc/watchdog/Linux-Watchdog.html

Comment: goddamit!  my kgdb session kept getting screwed up and I couldn't figure out what was going on.  Freaking hardware watchdog!  I forgot to disable it.  Since I don't need debug the kernel for a few months sometimes, I forget all of these details. I need to write a readme to remind myself.

Comment: $ echo 'V' | sudo tee /dev/watchdog # did nothing under Debian bookworm/sid. ps-e | grep watchdogd; shutdown -> "Watchdog0 did not stop". My UEFI lacks a disable watchdog option.